# Sql Server Split and Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, concatenation

I have data in the following format in a sql server database table

```
[CPOID]  [ContractPO]        [ContractPOTitle]
1        10-SUP-CN-CNP-0001  Drytech
2        10-SUP-CN-CNP-0002  EC&M
```

I need to write a stored procedure to generate the following result

```
[CPOID]      [ContractPO]        [ContractPOTitle]   [ConcatField]
    1        10-SUP-CN-CNP-0001  Drytech            CNP-0001-Drytech            
    2        10-SUP-CN-CNP-0002  EC&M               CNP-0002-EC&M
```

where [ConcatField] generate the result using split the last two values of the [ContractPOTitle] column and combine with the [ContractPOTitle]

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Also, you may want to specify if the formating of the numbers will ever change, because if they do you will need to plan for that as well. You may want to read up on the [SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and the [CharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) functions as these functions will play an important role in what you are looking to accomplish.  EDIT: I forgot about the [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) function, you should become acquainted with this function as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ContractPO field is always the same length, you could just do:

```
SELECT 
    CPOID, 
    ContractPO, 
    ContractPOTitle, 
    RIGHT(ContractPO, 8) + '-' + ContractPOTitle as [ConcatField]
FROM MyTable
```

Assuming that the length of the ContractPO field is not fixed AND we have to rely on stripping out the text after the next to last '-', the following SQL will work. It's a bit ugly, but these types of operations are necessary because there doesn't appear to be a LASTINDEX function available out of the box in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
    CPOID, 
    ContractPO, 
    ContractPOTitle, 
    RIGHT(ContractPO, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ContractPO), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ContractPO)) + 1) - 1) + '-' + ContractPOTitle as [ConcatField]
FROM @myTable
```

Comment: Your code assumes that the ContractPO filed's format will not change, the OP will need to tell us what happens after10-SUP-CN-CNP-9999, is the next number 10-SUP-CN-CNP-10000? If so, this will cause your solution to break. A better approach would be to use SubString, CharIndex and Reverse instead.

Comment: @Mark You're correct, and I updated my answer to parse out the text after the second '-'. However, just wanted to point out that I did qualify my first answer with "If the ContractPO field is always the same length", since the OP didn't specify. =]